# Apache Shiro dynamic URL attribute

Tags: web, authorization, shiro

I can not understand whether Apache Shiro allows to authorize a Subject with dynamically changed parameters and specific business rules.

Let's say, I have a business rule: "A user can see only it's own documents". To request some document user must specify an id of this document in the URL:

```
my.domain.com/doc?docId=1234
```

In case when the document with id 1234 belongs to a current user it can be displayed otherwise it can not.

Does Apache Shiro allows **in general approach** to implement the logic such that? If yes, which classes and in which way I must use to do so?

Comment: Sounds like you would want to use XACML for this

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, couple of the easiest though:

- Programmatically check access: `SecurityUtils.getSubject().checkPermission("docs:"+ yourDocId);`
- Create a filter to parse the URL from the incomming request similar to: [PathMatchingFilter](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/PathMatchingFilter.java)

Comment: Does this mean I should create my own Subject implementation which will redirect to a separate class which provides a specific logic of some business rule? Does this mean that, first, I concatenate the string "docs:" with an id of document and, second, I break it back to a separate string and id?
Could you give a link on documentation, or some tutorial, or example how to implement such approach?